# Doing isEmpty, split, contains and replace manually

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, split

So I am working on a project that for certain reasons is limited to java squawk 1.4. Because of this, the `String` class does not contain the four methods in the title. I need those methods in my program, and have concluded that I have to make a Util class that performs the functions of those methods by itself.

First off, does this exist somewhere? Obviously my first reaction was to look into just copying the source from the `String` class, but the dependencies of those methods go far too deep for me to use.

Secondly, I am having trouble replicating the behaviour of `split(String regex)` and `replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`. `contains(String)` and `isEmpty()` are easy obviously, but I have run into trouble coding the others.

Right now, I have `split` working (Although it works in a different way than in jdk 7, and I do not want to get bugs).

```
public static String[] split(String string, char split) {
    String[] s = new String[0];
    int count = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < string.length(); x++) {
        if (string.charAt(x) == split) {
            String[] tmp = s;
            s = new String[++count];
            System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, s, 0, tmp.length);
            s[count - 1] = string.substring(x).substring(1);
            if (contains(s[count - 1], split + "")) {
                s[count - 1] = s[count - 1].substring(0, s[count - 1].indexOf(split));
            }
        }
    }
    return s.length == 0 ? new String[]{string} : s;
}
```

`Replace` is much harder to do, and I have been trying for hours now. This seems to be a question google / archives have never even ventured.

Comment: `String.split(String regex)` was present in Java 1.4... are you sure you need to reimplement it? (I don't know anything about Squawk, admittedly.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I am using something called sun squawk, and it does not exist in the String class.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reference for what *is* available? If it doesn't simply match a JDK version, it's going to be harder to provide alternative implementations...

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh sure, http://www.wbrobotics.com/javadoc/overview-summary.html is the javadocs for all of our available classes/methods.

Comment: @LouisWasserman http://i.imgur.com/suwdb.png Not exactly 1.4, nor 2. It's an implementation.

Comment: Answers should be answers, not edited into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the methods...

```
public static boolean isEmpty(String string) {
    return string.length() == 0;
}

public static String[] split(String string, char split) {
    return _split(new String[0], string, split);
}

private static String[] _split(String[] current, String string, char split) {
    if (isEmpty(string)) {
        return current;
    }
    String[] tmp = current;
    current = new String[tmp.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(tmp, 0, current, 0, tmp.length);
    if (contains(string, split + "")) {
        current[current.length - 1] = string.substring(0, string.indexOf(split));
        string = string.substring(string.indexOf(split) + 1);
    } else {
        current[current.length - 1] = string;
        string = "";
    }
    return _split(current, string, split);
}

public static boolean contains(String string, String contains) {
    return string.indexOf(contains) > -1;
}

public static String replace(String string, char replace, String replacement) {
    String[] s = split(string, replace);

    String tmp = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < s.length; x++) {
        if (contains(s[x], replace + "")) {
            tmp += s[x].substring(1);
        } else {
            tmp += s[x];
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```